# How to redirect domain from http to https using .htacces and cakephp

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, cakephp

My app is hosted on heroku, and I am using Cakephp API. I want it to be redirect to https://www. and enforcing the www. subdomain.

And, they have two domains point to the same app.

I have the follow code, in the /app/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

#apply if no https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off    
#Ignore when is local env or any staging env
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^local(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)heroku(.*) [NC]

RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

#apply if https
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
#Ignore when is local env or any staging env or subdoamin is www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^local(.*) [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(.*)heroku(.*) [NC]
RewriteRule .* https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,L,R=301]

#default from cakephp
RewriteRule ^$ webroot/ [L]
RewriteRule (.*) webroot/$1 [L]
```

I have the follow code, in the /app/webroot/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /

#redirect any request from .poa.br to .com.br
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)example\.poa\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com.br/$1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

But it doesn't work. Just the follows requests are redirect to https://www.example.com.br:

```
https://www.example.com.br 
https://www.example.poa.br 
http://www.example.poa.br
```

This option go to domain, but without https prefix.

```
http://www.example.com.br
```

The other options doesn't work (return DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN):

```
https://example.com.br 
http://example.com.br 
https://example.poa.br 
http://example.poa.br
```

Answer (score 4):

In cakephp3 I struggled with this. My solution was to change the first .htaccess file from

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*)   webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

TO

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]
    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Notice the 302, the reason I struggled is that the .htaccess got cached and made testing very difficult, I even went as far as delete all the cakephp code in the index.php in the webroot and just echo out 'test' Once I got it working I changed the 302 to 301 so that the .htaccess can hard cache in the browser. ( To test if values like HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto exist I var_dump($_SERVER) in the index.php file )

IF you are on a server without HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On 
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
    RewriteRule ^ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

    RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
    RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello make sure rewrite module is on before this works.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.yourwebsite.com/$1 [R,L]
```

and in your base url you need to add (s) to http.

I hope this helps you.

You can also add 'www'

just add this

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Hi Konjesh! It didn't work.

I believe rewrite module is on because I create some loop in my tests.

Comment: The result of your suggestion is the same of my code.

Answer (score 0):

We cannot redirect domain to www.domain in Heroku using .htaccess. We need configure it using Heroku command. See the articles:

https://github.com/Helabs/pah/wiki/Configuring-domain-on-Heroku

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains#add-a-custom-root-domain

I'm looking how to force https.

Answer (score 0):

Change in your cakephp project folder your htaccess file like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L] 

  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)http(\:|\%3A)(.*)$
  ReWriteRule .* - [F]    

  RewriteRule    ^$    webroot/    [L]
  RewriteRule    (.*) webroot/$1    [L]
</IfModule>
```

And be sur that your server (or your virtual host) listen to the port 443 (for https)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin subdomain@example.br
    ServerName subdomain.example.br
    ServerAlias subdomain.example.br
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain
    <Directory /var/www/subdomain/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews

        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny 
        Allow from All
    </Directory>

    ServerSignature Off
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin subdomain@example.br
    ServerName subdomain.example.br
    ServerAlias subdomain.example.br
    DocumentRoot /var/www/subdomain
    <Directory /var/www/subdomain/>
        Options -Indexes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews

        AllowOverride All
        Order Allow,Deny
        Allow from All
    </Directory>  
  SSLEngine on
  SSLProtocol all -SSLv2
  SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM

    SSLCertificateFile /[path to your CRT file]
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /[path to your PEM file]
    SSLCertificateChainFile [path to your CRT file]
    SSLCACertificatePath /etc/ssl/certs/
    SSLCACertificateFile /[path to your CRT file]
    ErrorLog /var/log/apache2/error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 0):

I made all configurations in /app/webroot/.htaccess

There is a trick to identify if request to Heroku is https.

Follow the code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#Identify if it is https
RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} !https

#ignore local env
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^local(.*) [NC]

#apply redirect in all subdomain
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)example\.com\.br$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com.br/$1 [NE,R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

We decided to redirect all request to naked domain, but if you want to change to www you coult implement the follow command.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://www.example.com.br/$1 [NE,R=301,L]
```

Thanks